# google apis console 'Javascript origins'

Tags: google-api

What is the significance of "Javascript Origins" in Google Api console ? Is it the path from  which google allow access to my scripts which may access it's API ?

While using a Google Api , what additional care I have to take , keeping the Javascript Origins in mind,  while uploading my .js files accessing Google Apis , so that they work properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using in [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication). I tried cross posting from "Javascript Origins" with my own JS using OAuth 2.0 access token, but it is not working. So it seems, JS gadget running only in  Google gadget environment will work.